# Reading xml data in 4 level nesting in DataSet using Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm using XML to store data. And have four level nesting as given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resrourceInfo>
    <month name="jan">
      <r>
         <rqstType></rqstType>
         <rsrceName></rsrceName>
         <dateRqstd></dateRqstd>
      </r>
      <r>
         <rqstType></rqstType>
         <rsrceName></rsrceName>
         <dateRqstd></dateRqstd>
      </r>
    </month>
    <month name="feb">
      <r>
         <rqstType></rqstType>
         <rsrceName></rsrceName>
         <dateRqstd></dateRqstd>
      </r>
      <r>
         <rqstType></rqstType>
         <rsrceName></rsrceName>
         <dateRqstd></dateRqstd>
      </r>
    </month>
</resourceInfo>
```

I want to treat this schema as

- All the months as Tables
- All the r as Rows
- All the tags inside r as Columns

I've used C# as given below

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DB.xml"));
```

But it's not working as expected.
Is there any other way I can do it ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML wasn't saved as a DataSet.  So you can do something like this

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                    "<resrourceInfo>" +
                        "<month name=\"jan\">" +
                          "<r>" +
                             "<rqstType>1</rqstType>" +
                             "<rsrceName>2</rsrceName>" +
                             "<dateRqstd>3</dateRqstd>" +
                          "</r>" +
                          "<r>" +
                             "<rqstType>4</rqstType>" +
                             "<rsrceName>5</rsrceName>" +
                             "<dateRqstd>6</dateRqstd>" +
                          "</r>" +
                        "</month>" +
                        "<month name=\"feb\">" +
                          "<r>" +
                             "<rqstType>7</rqstType>" +
                             "<rsrceName>8</rsrceName>" +
                             "<dateRqstd>9</dateRqstd>" +
                          "</r>" +
                          "<r>" +
                             "<rqstType>10</rqstType>" +
                             "<rsrceName>11</rsrceName>" +
                             "<dateRqstd>12</dateRqstd>" +
                          "</r>" +
                        "</month>" +
                    "</resrourceInfo>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            foreach (XElement month in doc.Descendants("month"))
            {
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add(month.Attribute("name").Value);
                foreach (XElement row in month.Elements("r"))
                {
                    if (dt.Rows.Count < 1)
                    {
                        foreach (XElement col in row.Elements())
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(col.Name.ToString(), typeof(int));

                        }
                    }
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (XElement col in row.Elements())
                    {
                        newRow[col.Name.ToString()] = col.Value;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: if I have to update the same xml document with new values, in that case can I use the same approach or if any tweak needs ? please let me know. Thank you